# Paypal integration with split payment in ios

Tags: ios, paypal, payment-gateway

I want to upgrade the payment(PayPal)system of an old app with MPL payment library implemented and I need to implement split payment for this app.My question is can I Use the new PayPal mobile sdk to do it or Do I need to implement it to server end.

Comment: What do you mean by split payment ?

Comment: by Split payment I mean to say Adaptive Payments where payment can be split into different account like between seller account who use the app to sell product and app developer account.

Answer (score 0):

use this you can split payment by following new mpl library

https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL